# Constant TCP requests and failed responses

Tags: tcp, loopback

I'm getting one of these per second:

```
457 205.494657  127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 68  49507→23454 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=16344 WS=32 TSval=630136859 TSecr=0 SACK_PERM=1

458 205.494702  127.0.0.1   127.0.0.1   TCP 44  23454→49507 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

Each time the source port is incremented by 1 and the destination is always 23454

I have closed every app, turned off wifi, no ethernet connect, and tried to close any process in the application monitor that had any network traffic.

Any help would be appreciated

```
Frame 457: 68 bytes on wire (544 bits), 68 bytes captured (544 bits) on interface 0
    Interface id: 0 (lo0)
    Encapsulation type: NULL/Loopback (15)
    Arrival Time: Mar 31, 2017 22:35:17.546056000 EDT
    [Time shift for this packet: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Epoch Time: 1491014117.546056000 seconds
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 1.066713000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 205.494657000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 457
    Frame Length: 68 bytes (544 bits)
    Capture Length: 68 bytes (544 bits)
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Frame is ignored: False]
    [Protocols in frame: null:ip:tcp]
    [Coloring Rule Name: TCP SYN/FIN]
    [Coloring Rule String: tcp.flags & 0x02 || tcp.flags.fin == 1]
Null/Loopback
    Family: IP (2)
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1, Dst: 127.0.0.1
    0100 .... = Version: 4
    .... 0101 = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
    Differentiated Services Field: 0x00 (DSCP: CS0, ECN: Not-ECT)
        0000 00.. = Differentiated Services Codepoint: Default (0)
        .... ..00 = Explicit Congestion Notification: Not ECN-Capable Transport (0)
    Total Length: 64
    Identification: 0x061b (1563)
    Flags: 0x02 (Don't Fragment)
        0... .... = Reserved bit: Not set
        .1.. .... = Don't fragment: Set
        ..0. .... = More fragments: Not set
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 64
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x0000 [validation disabled]
    [Header checksum status: Unverified]
    Source: 127.0.0.1
    Destination: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Can you confirm what OS you are using? If you are on Linux or Mac, you could use Netcat to start listening on TCP port 23454 and then capture the traffic with tcpdump to try and find out where it is coming from.